# sed regexp address range minus (or plus) number of lines

Tags: sed

I have multiple ICS files that contain something like:

```
...
PRIORITY:4
DESCRIPTION:this
  was
  a
  triumph
COMPLETED:20180101T160000
...
```

I am in interested in addressing the `DESCRIPTION` key. The key `DESCRIPTION` can occur anywhere in the ICS file. It is *not* always followed by the key `COMPLETED`.

Using `ed`, I would do it like this:

```
/DESCRIPTION/;/^[^ ]/-1p
```

which results in:

```
DESCRIPTION:this
  was
  a
  triumph
```

However, `sed` does not seem to have that capability:

```
sed -n '/DESCRIPTION/,/^[^ ]/-1p' filename
```

results in

> sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown command: `-'

Is there a way to do what I want using `sed`?

### Solving this particular problem

This problem can be solved by:

```
sed -n '/DESCRIPTION:/,/^\S/ { /\(DESCRIPTION\|^\s\)/p }' example.ics
```

But this feels very unwieldy and verbose.

`awk` also does not seem to support `/begpat/,/endpat/-1`, so you would end up with something like:

```c
BEGIN { endpat = "^(DESCRIPTION|\\s)" }
/^DESCRIPTION/, $0 !~ endpat {
    if ($0 ~ endpat) {print}
}
```

Comment: "I am in interested in addressing lines 1-3": Do you just want to print the first three lines no matter what, or you need to check for a match? In the former case, you can simply use `sed '3q'`

Comment: @matsib.dev No, I need to print the `DESCRIPTION` key of an ICS file, which can be anywhere, and which is spread out over multiple lines (the continuation starts with spaces).

Comment: thanks for updating the question; I was about to ask you to upload a sample text. It's clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were pretty close:

```
sed '/DESCRIPTION/p;//,/^[^ ]/!d;//d' filename
```

Would do what you want. Why?

- You can define a range and drop everything outside that range with `/start/,/stop/!d`
- Then you want to delete the last line of the match also. A following `//d` would do so (the empty pattern `//` matches the last pattern, thus the `/stop/` line)
- But in your case that pattern also matches the first line. Bad luck! So let's `p`rint it before and you get the command I did show (again using the empty pattern)

**Update with different approaches**

In your comment you called this a "workaround", which it is from some point of view. And actually, for myself I would choose a different, more `sed`ish approach:

```
sed '/^ /{H;d;};x;/^DESCRIPTION/!d' filename
```

This should feel natural for `sed` lovers, but maybe strange at the first sight for some. It follows the "*wish-I-could-remember*"-approach. What is that? Each time you come to a line without indention, you think "I wish I could remember the lines before, whether they are worth to be printed". Then we simply assume we have them in our memory, the hold space, so we can simply e`x`change pattern space and hold space and `d`elete it if it doesn't start with `DESCRIPTION` (if it starts with, it's gonna be printed by default).

The nice thing about `x` is, that every line not indented will be in the hold space automatically, so we just need to add the indented lines to the hold space with `H`. That what the `/^ /{H;d;}` part does (the `d` is to avoid output or further processing for those lines).

Now, the opposite is what a programmer would do. They would probably do a loop like this:

```
sed '/DESCRIPTION/!d
  :loop
  N;/\n[^ ].*/!bloop
s///' filename
```

That is, drop everything until we meet the `DESCRIPTION` keyword, then start a loop to collect lines with `N` and loop until there is a line with a non-space `\n[^ ].*`. In that case remove that last line (once more taking advantage of the empty pattern).

That works, too, but that's not the typical way to do things in `sed`.

Comment: I like it! So I guess there's no `/pat/-n` or `/pat/+n` in `sed`, and we always have to use workarounds like this?

Comment: Indeed there is no such concept in `sed` (GNU `sed` has a `/pat/,+42` thing to match an address plus the following 42 lines, but that's different from what you want). I updated my answer to show completely different approaches to the problem. Decide for yourself which one doesn't feel like a workaround for you. Just remember: If you are used to hammer and nails, turning a screwdriver may feel like a workaround, but it is mainly a different approach fitting the tool.

Comment: Wow, there is a lot here to process, but I do recognize some stuff from when I was reading O'Reilly's "sed & awk". I guess I just assumed that `sed` was some kind of evolution over `ed`, and that whatever worked for `ed` (w|sh)ould work for `sed`. But I see now that although they share some similarities, they also quite differ. Thanks for taking the time to write such an elaborate answer, much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome. `sed` is more like a editing replacement for `grep`. The `s` is for stream which describes the main difference to `ed`: The file is streamed from beginning to end, no stepping back like in `ed`, thus also no `/pat/-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sed supports address ranges like this:

```
sed -n '/string1/,/string2/p file
```

In your case try using `-E` option for extended regular expressions.

```
sed -nE '/this/,/^[^ ]/p' filename
```

Comment: OK, that's exactly what I got. Can you also tell me how to "subtract" one line from the address range, as I did using `ed` (`/one/,/two/-1`)?

Comment: Don't think what you want is possible with `sed`. Would be happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: @suspectus Of course it's possible, you just do it differently in `sed` than with `ed`